# Make an application replace existing Application

Tags: android, google-play

I have 2 Applications 1 with Ads and 1 without Ads.

I created one without ads and then copied the project in eclipse.  I named the new project AdFree.  I then proceeded to add Ads to the other project.  Now, both Projects have the same com.mycompany.myapp name so when I tried to upload it it said I already had a project with that name even though the APK's where named differently.

I want it so if they have the Free (Ad based version) version and they purchase the one without ads, it will replace the Free Version that is already there.

Comment: You cannot do this. You cannot have two apps in the marketplace which replace one another when downloaded. You must have two different apps, and the user must uninstall the free version after downloading the paid version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that. You have two solutions:

A) Make two different versions, with two different package names. This way the user will have to uninstall the ads supported version when he buys the ad-free one.

B) Make a single app, ad supported, with the possibility to remove ads with In-app biling service (This will require a little research, but I think the result is better, since you have to deal with a single app).

There should be more options to handle your problem, but these are the most common solutions.

Comment: Thanks,  I figured but was hoping I was missing something.